# JavaScript mask for Brasil phone number

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, maskedinput

Currently I'm using jquery.maskedinput for verious mask formats, but it's not working for phone numbers.

In Brasil we used to have all numbers in the format (99)9999-9999. But lately, in a few cities, cell phones are using (99)99999-9999, while their normal phones and the rest of the country remain (99)9999-9999.

jquery.maskedinput seems to not support 2 formats on the same input where a character in the middle of the string may or may not be present. As I can see in its documentation, I could have (99)9999-9999 and (99)9999-99999, but that would confuse users.

Is there any other mask plugin/framework that allows me to validate both (99)9999-9999 and (99)99999-9999?

Edit: I created a full test using harry and Dmitrii solutions: http://jsfiddle.net/NSd6g/ `$('#full').inputmask('(99)9999[9]-9999');`

I'm gonna wait a bit more to see if I can find an even better solution. The perfect one wouldn't require the red message, second group would have 4 digits by default. And, if third group would get a fifth digit, only then second group would get its fifth space, moving third group's first digit into second group's fifth. lol kinda hard to understand, sorry!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could achieve this using [jquery.inputmask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask) as simple as:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#test').inputmask('(99)9999[9]-9999');
});
```

Try this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DAAJk/).

To skip the optional part while typing into the input you need to type space or the char following the optional part in the mask (hyphen in this case).

Comment: Your mask isn't working for me. I can't get the fifth one to be skipped, when I type the first number of third group it goes to fifth of second group. If first number of second group could be "number or space" it could work.

Comment: It worked lol! I'd need to add a note explaining to type space if 4 numbers are to be used :P

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention this :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm Brazilian too.

At my job we don't actually use the "-" char in the middle for those type of masks, so there's no confusion... the final mask would be the following: `(99)99999999?9`

It's a bit harder to the final user to identify a wrongly typed phone number this way, but it works.

Another way I know is building the regex in JS and then using it with another plugin, like, for example, [jQuery Validate](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/).

Comment: lol yes that could be done, but 8 or 9 digits all together is hard to read and indeed easy to mistype. Could you provide a regex that would work with validate?

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery mask you can only have the trailing characters be optional. Not ones in the middle  on the input.

My suggestion would be to have 3 input boxes, one for each part of the number with the optional character at the end of the middle input. Then concatenate the inputs on submit.

like so:

```
 (<input id="phone2" />)<input id="phone3" />-<input id="phone4" />

jQuery(function($){
  $("#phone2").mask("99");
  $("#phone3").mask("9999?9");
  $("#phone4").mask("9999");
});
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Rge83/1/

To make it more user friendly, a script to move to the next input once the current one has been filled can be added + some css to make the inputs look more like one.

Comment: Good idea, I did some tests with it: http://jsfiddle.net/6NXWW/ But I really wanted a mask to keep it all together

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion: "(99) [9] 9999-9999"

Comment: at least for me it is more natural, if you want to type a number with 8 numbers, just hit a space in the first number and that's it...
aesthetically is better too... (11) 9 1234-5678 or (11)  1234-5678
at least for me...

Answer (score 0):

```
//Configuração para celular com nono digito
$('#Seletor').focusout(function () {
    var phone, element;
    element = $(this);
    element.unmask();
    phone = element.val().replace(/\D/g, '');
    if (phone.length > 10) {
        element.mask("(99) 99999-999?9");
    } else {
        element.mask("(99) 9999-9999?9");
    }
}).trigger('focusout');
```

Answer (score 0):

Some updates 10 years later:

- **jQuery is still alive** (yes!)
- all **mobiles in Brazil have 9 digits** now (besides 2 digits from area code)
- all **Brazilian landlines still have 8 digits** (besides area code)

So in order to have a field accepting both mobiles or landlines I prefer a **dynamic mask that will automatically adjust itself to "5+4" or "4+4"** depending on how many digits were typed.

Example:

```js
$('#ContactPhone')
  // by default we expect a mobile (5+4 digits)
  // so the initial mask splits 5+4 and if someone pastes 9 digits 
  // the separator position won't be changed causing a blip

  .inputmask('(99) 99999-999[9]')
  .on('change keyup paste', function () {
    var digits = $(this).val().replace(/\D/g, '').length;

    // ... if there are only 8 digits we reformat as 4+4 - 
    // but yet letting space for another digit (which would reformat the mask back to 5+4)
    if (digits == 10)
      $(this).inputmask('(99) 9999-9999[9]');
    else
      $(this).inputmask("(99) 99999-9999");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

And now ...

```
$(selector).inputmask({ mask: ['(99) 9999-9999', '(99) 99999-9999'], keepStatic: true });
```

Order of array items matters.